howto gnome-terminal source some env variable and alias statement
i want to set up my work environment for different terminal tabs quickly. For that I have some statements in a script e.g.:
gnome-terminal --title "A TITLE" --tab --profile Red-White -- bash -c "source ~./envs/setEnv.sh; exec bash"

cat setENVS.sh:
echo Hallo there
alias instdir='cd /local0/biologics/instances/instsp-T8/'
complete -C complete-ant-cmd.pl ant
export incarnation='INCARN1'
export instsp='TEST123'
export port='41201'
PS1="$PS1-- INSTANCE=${_magenta}\${incarnation-<unset>}-\${instsp-<unset>}:\${port-<unset>}${_coloff}\n"

How ever this does not work. The "PS1" and the "alias" are not set.
Export variables is working.
On so does this sourceing, meaning the script works:
.  setENVS.sh

Does anybody have a solution for this?
Thanks.

bash --rcfile

aliases, non-exported functions, and non-exported variables are absolutely the private business of a given shell, therefore they are not passed on during an exec.

Maybe it is not possible, but since it opens a new bash, the private stuff is for the new window.

The concept of "window" doesn't matter here at all. You explicitly ask one bash to define some aliases and then to exec another bash. I explained why it doesn't work. In the mean time I believe KamilCuk's solution should work, have you tried that?

Yes this works: gnome-terminal --title "A TITLE" --tab --profile Red-White -- bash --rcfile setENVS.sh
